# How i verify token, that was stored in cookie httpOnly on browser?

Tags: token, verify, cookie-httponly

i use express in back end and this is my token was stored in browser
[image]

My question is "how i verify or get the value as "access_token" name was stored in cookie httpOnly to my expressjs app"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express has a package called `cookie-parser` on npm you can install it using `npm install --save cookie-parser`.
Then initialize it like this

```js
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Which lets you access `req.cookies` in your route.

Comment: And i forget add { withCredentials: true } in request to server,